# How to extract full set of features from an existing pcap file using tshark or any other tool?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, feature-extraction, tshark

I am new to network traffic analysis.

I have used the following Tshark command, but no luck.

C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -r C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\IDS-augustdocuments\iscxdataset\testbed13jun.pcapCopy\split\small_00057_20100613213752.pcap  separator=, -R "tcp.dat
a" -T fields frame.number -e appName -e totalSourceBytes > C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\IDS-augustdocuments\iscxdataset\testbed13jun.pcapCopy\split\18oct.csv
tshark: "=" was unexpected in this context.

Any suggestions to extract features like Direction ( for the flows), totalSourceBytes, totalDestinationBytes, totalDestinationPackets, totalSourcePackets, sourceTCPFlagsDescription etc.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -r C:\Users\Ravi\Desktop\IDS-augustdocuments\iscxdataset\testbed13jun.pcapCopy\split\small_00057_20100613213752.pcap -T fields -e ip.src > C:
\output.txt      This command is working. I have tried and tested this, but what I need is the fields like appName, Direction ( of the flow like L2L, L2R etc.), totalSourcePackets etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Bro IDS or Argus (Auditing Network Activit).

Argus example:

racluster -L0 -m proto -r filepcap.arg  -s proto saddr daddr spkts dpkts sbytes dbytes

```
Proto            SrcAddr            DstAddr  SrcPkts  DstPkts     SrcBytes     DstBytes 
   udp     84.125.xxx.xxx            0.0.0.0     2634     2580       205131       317889
   tcp     84.125.xxx.xxx            0.0.0.0    34143    42585      6078099     48276978
   arp     84.125.xxx.xxx       84.xxx.xxx.x        3        3          126          180
```

Best Regards,

Comment: @Alfon , I will try this and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @Alfon, I tried to install and configure Argus on Ubuntu 14.04 using the link http://nsmwiki.org/index.php?title=Argus#Getting_Started . But I could not get Argus running. Looks like I have I some issues with dependencies. Is there a detailed installation guide for the same?

Comment: I used Bro IDS to get the required fields from the conn.log file. Configure the Bro IDS, use the command "bro -r <your pcap file.pcap>" and inspect the logs like conn.log, dns.log, http.log, etc for different information from the pcap log file.    Below are the fields.                                                                                          ts                    uid               id.orig_h   id.orig_p id.resp_h id.resp_p proto service duration orig_bytes resp_bytes conn_state

Comment: @Ravi: sudo apt-get install argus-server argus-client     or read: http://qosient.com/argus/downloads.shtml  More information about Argus in my blog - > https://seguridadyredes.wordpress.com/category/argus/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use quotes:
separator=","

Answer (score 0):

I used Bro IDS to get the required fields from the conn.log file. 
1) Configure the Bro IDS
(Follow this link to install Bro IDS)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-bro-ids-2-2-on-ubuntu-12-04
2) Start the Bro IDs
3) use the command "bro -r your pcap file.pcap" and this will generate a .log files in the current directory. 
4) Inspect the logs like conn.log, dns.log, http.log, etc. for different information from the pcap log file.